# Property in Model-View design

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, django-models

(Caveat: I am fairly new to Django and MVC model)

Assuming that I have the following classes in the models:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Project(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ProjectMember(models.Model):
   unique_together = ('project', 'member')
   project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
   member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
```

Now, I would like to get the list of all projects for a member. So I have added:

```
@property
def projects(self):
    return Project.objects.filter(projectmember__member=self)
```

But I also can add this filter in a view or built extra function to do it. Is there any guidance? Should model contain any properties? It makes the code reusable, but I can achieve the same with extra function, which does not clutter the model.

Answer (score 1):

Models can indeed have properties and additional methods. This is actually quite common as a lot of operations on a model could go into a method. There's no need to move this to a separate function if a property or method is suitable.

A separate function would be useful when it deals with multiple models or does something that doesn't really relate to one model in particular.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally considered good practice to follow a "fat models, thin views" structure within Django. Meaning that the less logic you put into your views the better. Obviously some view logic is unavoidable, but in general a lot of tasks like the one you are trying to do are better suited to being on the model.

Answer (score 1):

```
Project.objects.filter(projectmember__member=self)
```

This is a very simple query and im sure that view is much better place to it without any methods or properties. In addition, you do not have to remember what mean attribute `projects` in model `Project`.

I would move that code in separate method if there were some more logic to add in it, caching or something and if that method could be called from many parts (not one specific view) of application.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use reverse relation:

`member.project_set.all()`

Which creates automatically by django, more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#m2m-reverse-relationships

Comment: I think you can use M2M-through relationship:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships
And then lookup will be really easy.

Comment: I am aware of ManyToManyField option, but there are other fields in my project which I removed to make the question easier to read. So basically I need cross reference table - ProjectMember to accommodate other bits.